# Eclipse Helios can't create ECore from XSD if the xsds are in the workspace

Tags: xsd, eclipse-emf

I have a bunch of XSD files in a folder under an Empty EMF project. I select new generator model, and it asks for a model source. If I select the main xsd from the browser workspace option (from a folder in the empty emf project), the import does not work. 
I get Error: XSD type reference blabla is unresolved Uri:platform/resource....

If I copy the workspace folder to some other location and browse that via Browser file system option, everything works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody comes across the same problem, one of the schemas included another xsd with xsd name written in lowercase letters. The clue was given in this thread in the Eclipse community forums: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/786530/#msg_786530